# How to destroy MainActivity first and start it again once receive notification

Tags: android

Hello I am working on android app where I am using GCM concept. Once app receive notification then on click I am starting MainActivity.

If MainActivity is already running and app receive notification then already running MainActivity should finish and restart, and if it not running then simply start it.

There should be flag to do this same. can anyone help me what is that flag ?

`GcmIntentService.java`.

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        String message = extras.getString("message").toString();
        String notificationTitle = extras.getString("title");

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification(message, notificationTitle);
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg, String notificationTitle) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notification_message", msg);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notification", true);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setDefaults(-1);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to use PendingIntent : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: @HareshChhelana I am using Pending Intent but my question is that if `MainActivity` is already running and app receive notification then already running `MainActivity` should finish and restart.

Comment: have you try to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ?

Comment: @Williams what are you showing in the `MainActivity`? How about calling an initializing method to repopulate things shown on the activity?

Comment: @HareshChhelana yes not working

Comment: @Sufian But I don't want to repopulate things when user go on `MainActivity` without notification.

Comment: Try to replace this code : PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,(int) (Math.random() * 100), notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: @Williams you can avoid that by calling the init method in `onCreate()` and in the method called upon notification. I think closing and opening an activity is not really a good design, and it's better to avoid activity flags (it may cause some side-effects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `MainActivity` is not running, it will be opened/started (no problem here). In case it is already running then the `onNewIntent()` method (in your `MainActivity`) will be called. So you can override it as following:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    init(); //this method will reload the data, or whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: If you don't get the desired results then share your `<Activity>` tag of `MainActivity` in your manifest.

Comment: Btw you posted a comment that you changed the `launchMode`. You may like to read [this article](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) as I too tumbled over it (don't remember exactly but it was either something while starting or finishing the `Activity`)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
           .setContentTitle(sender)
           .setContentText(message);

                            // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(LoginScreen.class);

// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification=mBuilder.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

// Play default notification sound
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

// Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(msg_ID,notification);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this in your main activity to start Activity:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(notificationIntent);
finish();
```

In your Notification activity intent reopen the Main Activity :

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting. I'm pretty much sure Android is not developed in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to call `finish()` and then restart `MainActivity`

```
finish(); //Close current activity
startActivity(getIntent()); //Restart it
```

Comment: How to do this in `GcmIntentService.java` file ?